# Error : Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

While creating the NestJS with MSSQl application after creating the ormconfig and take the reference .

Getting the warning message as :

```
[Nest] 12236   - 05/23/2020, 6:27:56 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23
```

Any idea on that. Please let me know if any detail required.

ORM config details.

```
{
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "REETPC",
    "port": 1433,
    "username": "sa",
    "password": "password1",
    "database": "test12",
    "synchronize": true,
    "entities": [
       "dist/Entity/*.js"
    ],
    "cli": {
       "entitiesDir": "src/entity"
    }
 }
```

Package.JSOn file details.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "mssql": "^6.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection options you should add:

```
extra: {
  options: {
     enableArithAbort: true // or `false`. Just set it explicitly to silence the warning message
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you very uch it is resolved in added below line in ormconfig.json  "extra": {
      "options": {
         "enableArithAbort": true
      }
   }

Answer (score 1):

For thoose like me who face this issue but use env variables to connect to their databases you need to set TYPEORM_DRIVER_EXTRA like so (`enableArithAbort` needs to be inside an `option` object)

```
TYPEORM_DRIVER_EXTRA='{ "options": { "enableArithAbort": true } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your `ormconfig` to let anyone help you. By the way, it looks like a problem with the `node-mssql` driver rather than with TypeoORM itself.

Comment: added both ormconfig and pakage.json details on question.. I am using mssql driver.